# Getting Pip to install in specific Python versions for IBM Watson use

Tags: python, pip, speech-to-text, watson

I have two versions of Python in my /usr/bin directory. Python2.7 and Python3.6. Entering "Python --version" in a terminal I get "Python 2.7.15" back. I'd like to add watson_developer_cloud to 2.7. However when I enter

```
pip install watson_developer_cloud
```

watson_developer_cloud shows up in /usr/lib/Python3.6 and not /usr/lib/Python2.7.

**Question:** How do I get watson_developer_cloud in Python2.7?

I am trying to get Watson speech-to-text configured to use sttClient.py. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `python -m pip install watson_developer_cloud`

Comment: You may try `pip2` or `pip2.7` commands, check if it is available. But maybe you will need to install it, since pip3 and pip2 are whole different package managers.

Comment: "python -m pip install watson_developer_cloud" returns, "no module named pip".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pip: dealing with multiple Python versions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812520/pip-dealing-with-multiple-python-versions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can tell pip which version of python you wish to use:

```
#Install x library using python 2.7
$ python-2,7 -m pip install x
```

It seems that is is the best recommendation since it supports all versions of Python, and in all forms of virtualenv. You can read more about this here: [pip: dealing with multiple Python versions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812520/pip-dealing-with-multiple-python-versions?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: "python2.7 -m pip install watson_developer_cloud" returns "/usr/bin/python2.7: No module named pip"

Comment: Okay, now I've got both pip2 and pip3 packages (v10.0.1-1-1) installed. Unclear to me why there are separate packages for Python2 and Python3. Watson developer cloud installed fine in /usr/lib/Python2.7.15. Thanks.